# SQL - search by beginning of a word

Tags: sql, extract

I want to write an SQL SERVER statement that searches for the beginning of a word in a string that starts with something.

For example, if I search for 'em' on the Company record, I should get:

Emily, Inc

The Emmmy

NOT

Forget Them

Lemming, LLC

I can do this in PHP by extracting/slicing the string into an array and searching the beginning of each words.
But how I would write this query in SQL server without resorting to Stored procedures/functions?

Comment: Do mention the SQL engine you are using! For eg: Postgres supports regex thus making it much easier to search.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

JW's answer will work for entries where Em is at the very beginning of the field.

If you also need to retrieve values where the word is not the first in the string, try:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE CompanyName LIKE 'Em%' or CompanyName LIKE '% Em%'
```

(This is assuming all word are separated by a space.)

Comment: Please note that this is not a very efficient solution and will run slow on large tables.

Comment: This does not work for double-barrelled names joined with a hyphen and other non-space delimited words.

Comment: Agreed, as per the assumption stated in my original answer.

Comment: That can be fixed with `LIKE 'Em%' or CompanyName LIKE '%[^a-z]Em%'` - still slow though!

Comment: How would you query or design such a table not to be slow?

Comment: @mathkid91: It depends on your requirements and how much data you have. First, make sure your RDBMS indexes your field. Or create your own separate indexing table where you separate every word in CompanyName into distinct records, then query that instead.

Answer (score 3):

use `LIKE`

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE CompanyName LIKE 'Em%'
```

Comment: and i guess you need to search for `FULL TEXT SEARCH`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [`CONTAINS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx), something like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE CONTAINS(CompanyName, 'Em*');
```

Comment: note that in sql server, you can use `contains` ONLY on  tables which are `full-text indexed`. 
more info on setting up full text search here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/get-started-with-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -3):

For MS Access:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Company_Name LIKE 'Word*'
```

For more *standard* DBMSs:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Company_Name LIKE 'Word%'
```